# Need Help to create a folder with Timestamp using EST Timezone With DST(DaylightSavingTime)

Tags: java, maven

i tried with below code , when i use `${build.time}`， it create one `hr` behind as `DST` is on now. I want created with exact time.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>timestamp-property</id>
      <phase>validate</phase> 
      <goals>
        <goal>timestamp-property</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <name>build.time</name>
        <pattern>MM-dd-YYYY-hh-mm-SS</pattern>
        <locale>en_US</locale>
        <timezone>EST</timezone>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: If you want it to adjust for DST, don't use `EST`, use `America/New_York`.

Comment: I tried before and i just tried as well it just ignores   <timeZone>America/New_York</timeZone> and it creates with ${build.time}.        When i replace the same with EST it creates the folder with the format i want but it creates  an hr back.

Comment: Is that because you've written `<timeZone>` instead of `<timezone>`? I dunno, I never use maven, but I know that `EST` in Java doesn't use DST.

Comment: It created now with the time i want. Thankyou

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to adjust for DST, don't use `EST`, use `America/New_York`.

For historical reasons, the JDK doesn't apply daylight savings time adjustments to EST (although it does to other timezone abbreviations like PST).

You are better off just avoiding three-letter timezone abbreviations entirely, they are ambiguous. From [the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html):

> For compatibility with JDK 1.1.x, some other three-letter time zone IDs (such as "PST", "CTT", "AST") are also supported. **However, their use is deprecated** because the same abbreviation is often used for multiple time zones (for example, "CST" could be U.S. "Central Standard Time" and "China Standard Time"), and the Java platform can then only recognize one of them.